# "Python has stopped working" when using PyDev Eclipse plugin

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev

When working with the Python plugin PyDev for Eclipse on Windows 7, I sometimes get following popup error message:

[image]

```
Python funktioniert nicht mehr
Ein Problem hat die richtige Ausführung dieses Programms verhindert. Schließen Sie das Programm.
```

I am able to close that window and to continue to work with PyDev. However, those error messages are annoying and I would like to understand/fix the issue.

There are some general hints on how to disable window error reporting:

[Suppress message: "python.exe has stopped working"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16987632/suppress-message-python-exe-has-stopped-working)

[Python has stopped working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47828821/python-has-stopped-working)

I don't want to completely disable error reporting on windows.

=> Is there some PyDev or Eclipse setting that I could use to address this issue?

Answer (score 0):

The usual reason this happens is because PyDev obtains code-completion information by creating a python shell and communicating with it so that it imports a module and does some `dir` calls in it or its classes to get information (and then, sometimes a module is misbehaving so that the mere fact of importing it or getting its contents makes that python shell crash).

Usually the error log contains information on which module was being loaded when that happens (see: http://www.pydev.org/faq.html#HowdoIReportaBUG for how to access the error log) so that you can track it down.